# React-native/Expo header buttons are not showing

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-navigation

I follow youtube tutorial on React Native with Expo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mJ3bGvy0WAY but since video is almost 1 year old some things have changed, and so I have no idea why my Stack.Screen basically doesn't work, like I can't see its title in the Expo Go and therefore I can't see header buttons. ChatGPT said that Stack.Screen has to be used within Stack.Navigation but I can't find any proof in the React Native docs.

app\index.js

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { View, ScrollView, SafeAreaView } from "react-native";
import { Stack, useRouter } from 'expo-router';

import { COLORS, icons, images, SIZES } from '../constants';
import { Nearbyjobs, Popularjobs, ScreenHeaderBtn, Welcome } from '../components';

const Home = () => {
    const router = useRouter();

    return ( 
        <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: COLORS.lightWhite }}>
            <Stack.Screen
                options={{
                    headerStyle: { backgroundColor: COLORS.lightWhite },
                    headerShadowVisible: false,
                    headerLeft: () => (
                        <ScreenHeaderBtn iconUrl={icons.menu} dimension="60%" />
                    ),
                    headerRight: () => (
                        <ScreenHeaderBtn iconUrl={icons.profile} dimension="100%" />
                    ),
                    headerTitle: "Beta"
                }}
             />

            <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
                <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: SIZES.medium }}>
                    <Welcome

                     />
                    <Popularjobs />
                    <Nearbyjobs />
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}

export default Home;
```

app\ScreenHeaderBtn.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { TouchableOpacity, Image } from 'react-native'

import styles from './screenheader.style'

const ScreenHeaderBtn = ({ iconUrl, dimension, handlePre }) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity>
      <Image 
        source={iconUrl}
      />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}

export default ScreenHeaderBtn
```

I feel like I tried everything honestly, otherwise I wouldn't post the question here. Thank you!